# Invoking problem with function defined in exec()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm practising function definition in exec(), but when invoking the function, some weird behaviors confused me, kindly need your help!

In Practice-1, even I can find the 'exec_func' object in locals(), but still got error 'NameError: name 'exec_func' is not defined' when invoking the function.
In Practice-2 and Practice-3, the function can be executed perfectly.

```
### Practice-1 ###
# Define exec_func in function body, and invoked directly
def main_func():
    x = 5
    exec('''def exec_func(p1, p2):
    return p1 + p2''')
    print('locals = ', locals())
    print('exec_func=', exec_func(x, 3))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()

### Practice-2 ###
# Define exec_func in function body, and invoked through locals()
def main_func():
    x = 5
    func = None
    exec('''def exec_func(p1, p2):
    return p1 + p2''')
    print('locals = ', locals())
    func = locals()['exec_func']
    print('exec_func=', func(x, 3))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()

### Practice-3 ###
# define exec_func out of function body, and invoked directly
x = 5
dic = None
exec('''def exec_func(p1, p2):
     return p1 + p2''')
print('locals = ', locals())
print('exec_func=', exec_func(x, 3))
```

So, basically what confused me are:
1. In Practice-1, why 'exec_func' cannot be invoked directly, even it is in locals().
2. Practice-3 is similar to Practice-1, difference is only that, one is in function body, another is out of function body, why Practice-3 executed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Practise-1 code will work if you set it in `globals` like below. By default any symbols (your function here) will be looked for only in `globals`.

```
def main_func():
    x = 5
    exec('''def exec_func(p1, p2):
    \treturn p1 + p2''')
    print('locals = ', locals())
    globals()['exec_func'] = locals()['exec_func']
    print('exec_func=', exec_func(x, 3))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()
```

Output:

```
locals =  {'x': 5, 'exec_func': <function exec_func at 0x10f695378>}
exec_func= 8
```

Here is the docs for locals

```
Help on built-in function locals in module builtins:

locals()
    Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.

    NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in
    the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
    covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees.
(END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I even practised exec('''def exec_func(p1, p2): \treturn p1 + p2''', globals()), it also works perfectly.
I tried dis.dis(main_func), so I have the idea that it is trying to find the object in global namespace(LOAD_GLOBAL), rather than local namespace.
I was confused, because I thought that, the interpreter first trys to find the object in local namespace, if not found, then it will go to global namespace.
Taking my question, the object is in locals(), I thought the interpreter should use the object in locals(), rather than to look at global namespace.