# Python problem with function declaration inside exec

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't I declare a function in exec within another function ? I really have no idea why it's happening, is there a way to make this work. I found this: [Invoking problem with function defined in exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846074/invoking-problem-with-function-defined-in-exec) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, in my case I wan't the exec code to be arbitrary.

```py
def test():
    exec("""
def this():
    print('this')

def main():
    this()

main()
""")

test()
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/t.py", line 12, in <module>
    test()
  File "/t.py", line 2, in test
    exec("""
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in main
NameError: name 'this' is not defined
```

When I do the exec outside a function it works just fine, why ? :

```py
exec("""
def this():
    print('this')

def main():
    this()

main()
""")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure why, but it works if you add an empty dictionary as `globals` to `exec`. What exactly do you want to achieve with this, or is just purely out of academic interest?

Comment: `this` and `main` are both defined in the local scope of `test`, but `main` still looks in the *global* scope for the definition of `this`. When you pass a `dict`, that is used as the namespace, so the call to `main` will look there instead for the definition of `this`.

Comment: Be very sure you *need* `exec` before worrying about this, though. Just because (you think) you *can* use `exec` doesn't mean you *should* be using it.

Comment: Yes thank you, I didn't know about namespace dict in exec. And that was purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Provide explicit globals dictionaries to execute code "as if" it were run at top-level.

---

Python uses *lexical* scoping, which roughly means that names are looked up as per the nesting in source code. For example, a nested function can access an outer function's variable.

```py
def foo():
    bar = 12
    def qux():
        print(bar)  # nested scope accesses outer scope
    return qux
```

Notably, this kind of name lookup happens at source code compilation time – the compiler knows that both `foo` and `qux` access `bar`, so it must be made available to both. The inner function is directly compiled to look at the variable of the outer function.

If instead a function is *not* nested, its name lookup to non-local variables automatically goes to global scope.

```py
def qux():
    print(bar)  # top-level scope accesses global scope
```

This is a problem when we `exec` code in a function: A definition such as `def main(): this()` is compiled to lookup `this` at global scope, *but* `exec` runs in the current local scope of the function.

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

Thus, `this` is *looked up* globally but *defined* locally.<sup>1</sup> The compiler parses `def test` and the exec code separately, so it does not know that lookups are meant to be treated as nested.
As a result, the lookup fails.

In order to `exec` code "as if" it were run at top-level, it is sufficient to supply an explicit `globals` – for example a fresh namespace `{}` or the actual `globals()`.

```py
def test():
    exec("""
def this():
    print('this')

def main():
    this()

main()
""", {})
#    ^^ globals namespace for exec

test()
```

This means the code is now run in (its own) global namespace, which is where the lookup of functions searches as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>This can be checked by printing `globals()`/`locals()` and by inspecting the instructions of the function. `dis.dis(main)` in the exec would produce:

```non
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (this)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 POP_TOP
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

heres my attempt to make it work
from the error, i am guessing you can create an object by using `exec()` in global environment, but cant add an object to global environment using `exec()` in a function. thus the system sees it as a local `exec()` variable and failed to read it
so i tried to add a global declaration and it worked:

```
def test():
    exec("""
global this
def this():
    print('this')

def main():
    this()

main()
""")

test()
```

results:

```
this
```

however it may overwrite other global variables because i can now call `this()` outside of `test()`:

```
>>> this()
this
```